# Ошибка HRESULT 0x8007007E при регистрации модуля. Как исправить?

Tags: windowsinstaller, wix, msi

Разрабатываю msi установщик. После сборки, при установке, получаю сообщение об ошибке: не удалось зарегистрировать модуль SafeuseShell.dll HRESULT 0x8007007E (этот код означает, что указанный модуль не найден).

Как исправить данный баг?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно обеспечить доступность ВСЕХ используемых dll, которые загружает ваша dll

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается нужно было установить Visual c++ Redistributables 2015